# making a universal db_access file

Tags: html, mysql, database, data-access

Working on a project where i am using wamp and phpmyadmin to make a website.  I am doing a little bit of databasing.  I would like to have a file that would could work on both my local database as well as my live database.  exp.

Local machine:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'exp_database';
mysqli_connect($server,'root','',$database);
```

Live:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'username';
$db_password = 'dbpass';
$database = 'exp_database';
$con=mysqli_connect($server,$db_username,$db_password,$database);
```

I have been looking for a tutorial or something that fits my situation.  I might be going about this all wrong, but please direct me in the right direction.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are calling functions from the PHP extension file `php_mysql` but you want to have a _generic_ file as your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
if ('localhost' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    // [] you are local
} else {
    // [] you are live
}
```